# Magento: Adding class to top links using liParams

Tags: magento

I have tried adding class using liParams but this is not getting added to all the links. Say, if I have 3 links as top links in the header, the class is getting added only to the second link. The first and the last links are being ignored. 
Ref: http://www.apptha.com/blog/how-to-add-or-edit-top-links-sections-in-magneto/

Now, the issue is that I have only two top links in the header and as a result, class is not getting added to them. Is it possible to add class to these two links? If so, please suggest the necessary changes. Thanks in advance for the help!

Here's the code that I have been trying..

```
<customer_logged_out>   
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>LOG IN</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>LOG IN</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>200</position><liParams>class="li-logged-out"</liParams><aParams>class="a-logged-out"</aParams></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>SIGN UP</label><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl"/><title>SIGN UP</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position><liParams>class="li-logged-out"</liParams><aParams>class="a-logged-out"</aParams></action>
    </reference>    
</customer_logged_out>
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried and what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Updated the question with the code. Here I am trying to add class to li elements for making some CSS changes. I noticed that class 'a-logged-out' is getting added to the anchor links but class 'li-logged-out' is not getting added to the li elements.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the links.phtml file adds by default 'first' and 'last' classnames, which are overriding the  values you're adding. Go into you're theme's copy of template/page/template/links.phtml and fix it from there.

I'm supposing the `.first` and `.last` classnames are there to help styling the links. 
Typical scenario I think would be to add margins, but to prevent margins from taking space before the first link and after the last link e.g.:

```
.link { margin: 0 15px; }
.link.first { margin-left: 0; }
.link.last { margin-right: 0; }
```

In this scenario you could make those redundant with a slightly different approach in CSS:

```
.link { margin-left: 30px }
.link:first-child { margin-left: 0; }
```